# jquery get attribute value when property is not set

Tags: jquery

I simply want to get the current value of a field's attribute.

This field has a default value like:

```
<input validation="defaultValue" />
```

When i want to get the validation attribute, i don't know if it has been updated before or if this is still the default value.

So the property get with `prop()` return `undefined` when the property is not set (not yet updated), and the `attr()` method return always the default value (that's not true actually for maintainability but that will be in the future).

Is there a method that check:

if property is set => return property
else return attribute

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This snippet will do:

```
var input = $("input");
var method = typeof input.prop("validation") != "undefined" ? "prop" : "attr";
input[method]("validation");

//Shortened to:
var input = $("input");
input[typeof input.prop("validation")!="undefined"?"prop":"attr"]("validation");
```

Explanation:

- If the property is not set `typeof ... "undefined"`, the `"prop"` string returns. Otherwise, the `"attr"` string returns.
- This string is used to select the right method of the `input` object, either `input["prop"]` (=`input.prop`) or `input["attr"]` (=`input.attr`).
- Finally, the method is invoked, passing `"validation"` as an argument, resulting in:

  1. The property (if existent) *or*
  2. The attribute (if the property doesn't exist).

I recommend to use `data-validation` instead of `validation`, to be HTML5-compliant.

### Update: A JQuery method:

```
(function($){
    /* Defines the curProp method - Getting the current property
     * When the property exists, the prop method is used. Otherwise: attr */
    $.fn.curProp = function(name){
        return this[typeof this.prop(name) == "undefined" ? "attr" : "prop"](name);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Yeah, i could check it myself, but isn't there a jquery method doing that ? (i use data-validation but the aim of the example was to be simple :)

Comment: See my updated answer. I have created a JQuery method for this purpose. Simply include the provided code at your JQuery library. From now on, you can use the `.curProp` method on any JQuery object.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I think that's a big miss in jquery.