# Can't get second radio button selected value

Tags: javascript

I have two pair of Radio Button. One pair for Gender and other for User type.
My problem is I cant get the selected value of second pair of Radio button that is User type.
Only get the selected value of first pair of radio button that is Gender.
Can u help me?

```
$('input:radio[name=user[user_type_id]]:checked').val();
$('input:radio[name=user[gender]]:checked').val();
```

Comment: create [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to get better help when it is javascript or jquery question..

Comment: $('input:radio[name=user[user_type_id]]:checked').val();

Comment: $('input:radio[name=user[gender]]:checked').val();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [jQuery(':radio')](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) Selector

If you use `val()` then it will not give value of the input:checked, it will return on or off only. To get get value of the radio button use the use the [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method:

//Html

```
<div>
<input type="radio" name="gender"  value="Male"/>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" /></div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="user" value="admin"/>
    <input type="radio" name="user" value="user" />
</div>
<input type="button" id="clickMe" value ="Click Me" />
```

//js

```
$('#clickMe').click(function(){

alert($('input[name=gender]:radio:checked').attr('value'));
    alert($('input[name=user]:radio:checked').attr('value'));

});
```

Ref:
[Get attribute name value of <input>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513809/jquery-get-attribute-name-value-of-input)
[jquery get attribute value when property is not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689757/jquery-get-attribute-value-when-property-is-not-set)

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjankala/UNXa2/) example